# how to use if else condition in My blade file in Laravel Applications?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need use if else conditions in My laravel blade file. to print different icons. this is My current blade file

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

I need like this one blade file

```
@if (Auth::user()->id)->exists()) {
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach

else
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

how can I gonfigure this?

Comment: add `@` before `if` and `else`. You are missing `@` in else. `@else
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)` and closing `@endif` is also missing.

Comment: occured following error **syntax error, unexpected end of file**

Comment: have you close `if` at the end of file by `@endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes I found in your code such as 
`else` without `@` and you are using `{` in first if which shouldn't be used. 
you are missing closing `@endif` as well.

Here is the code

```
@if (Auth::user()->id)->exists()) 
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach

@else
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>

  <hr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Following shows how if statements are used laravel blade

you can construct if statements using the @if, @elseif, @else, and @endif directives. These directives function identically to their PHP counterparts:

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    <p>I have one record!</p>
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    <p>I have multiple records!</p>
@else
   <p> I don't have any records! </p>
@endif
```

More Details : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade